# What could be the cause for not seeing the template toolset when starting up an AVEVA System Platform blank galaxy?

Tags: plc, scada

I am new to the AVEVA system platform. After taking the beginners course I wanted to try to establish communication between an actual PLC and a System platform. However, I can't do much after setting everything up on a virtual machine after creating a galaxy (default or empty).

The template toolset is not there for me to create any templates or create instances of default ones.
and any help is appreciated.